# Bootable USB doesn't work on every machines

Tags: linux, usb

I used unetbootin to make a bootable USB key (a BT4 persistant live cd)

But it wors only on a few machines. (only 1 out of 6 i tried)
Most of the time boot sequence get stuck on a blinking prompt cursor.

Ex:

> Attempting Boot From Floppy Drive (A:)
>
> Attempting Boot From USB Device
>
> _ <-- stuck...
>
> Then boot on HDD

Is it do to the usb key or machines that do not load mbr the same way??

thank you!

Edit: the stick is formated with MBR have 2 partitions. The first is FAT32 and active, second is ext3

PCs i have tested can boot on USB (at leat you can select a USB device for Boot)

Answer (score 1):

These two articles will get you up and running on all computer models.

First, if the BIOS supports boot from USB:
[How to Set BIOS to Boot From USB](http://www.ehow.com/how_5805266_set-bios-boot-usb.html)

Next, if the BIOS doesn't support it, the solution is to use a boot CD that can boot into USB:
[Boot From a USB Drive Even if your BIOS Won’t Let You](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/)